# find a change in the sequence of values in a column

Tags: sequence

I would like to add in 4 blank rows every time a formula or macro finds a change in value of more or less than 6.

We survey every 6m on a drill string and when I get the data back it is in a .csv file with rows of data starting with a multiple of six. But when we pull back our survey tool and start again from a different point it does not separate the values. Sometimes this might happen only a couple of times in a borehole, sometines it might happen 50 times. I need to find the change from e.g. 120 in cell a20 to 72 in a21. It is difficult at times to do this manually. Is there a way to find these changes and then separate the rows with 4 blank rows.

Thanks in advance.

I haven't tried anything as I am an intermediate user of excel. I have searched but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all cells in the column that you wish to find the difference of, go to conditional formatting and create a new rule with formulae. Type the formula in '=A2<>A1 +6' when 6 equals the value of the difference you normally have. Format the change with a colour so a cell is highlighted with that colour when there is a change in 'not' 6.